# Creating an MFA-protected role with AWS CDK bypasses MFA condition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an MFA-protected role granting `AdministratorAccess` which can be assumed by another user. I can get it to define the user and the permission policy of the role. However, when I define the MFA requirement, the principal and the permitted action is duplicated in the permission policy, which renders the MFA requirement condition useless.

My CDK code looks like this:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_iam as iam,
    core,
)


class AssumeRoleStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        user = iam.User(self, 'myuser')
        role = iam.Role(self, 'myrole',
                        assumed_by=iam.ArnPrincipal(user.user_arn),
                        max_session_duration=core.Duration.hours(8))
        role.add_managed_policy(iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name('AdministratorAccess'))
        role.assume_role_policy.add_statements(
            iam.PolicyStatement(principals=[user],
                                actions=['sts:AssumeRole'],
                                conditions={'Bool': {'aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent': True}})
        )
        user.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(actions=['sts:AssumeRole'], resources=[role.role_arn]))
```

The resulting permission policy of the role then looks as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678910:user/assume-role-myuserZ09A543B-1ULCILBM447SF"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678910:user/assume-role-myuserZ09A543B-1ULCILBM447SF"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is not what I want, because - as mentioned above - the user will be able to assume the role even without MFA present. What I want is the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678910:user/assume-role-myuserZ09A543B-1ULCILBM447SF"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I already tried defining the role without the `assumed_by` argument and adding the principal in the `assume_role_policy` instead, but a principal is required by the `iam.Role` class. Similarly, `iam.PolicyStatement` in `assume_role_policy.add_statements()` does not allow leaving out either the `principals` or the `actions` argument.

How can I create the role's permission policy without redundancies and without rendering conditions useless because of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. The solution is a combination of the one proposed by @Vikyol and the hints by the kind people over at [this Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5793):

You have to create a class that inherits from `iam.AccountRootPrincipal` and overrides the property `policy_fragment` so that the returned trust policy contains the `Conditions` block:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_iam as iam,
    core,
)


class MFAAccountRootPrincipal(iam.AccountRootPrincipal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def policy_fragment(self) -> iam.PrincipalPolicyFragment:
        return iam.PrincipalPolicyFragment(
            principal_json={'AWS': [self.arn]},
            conditions={'Bool': {'aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent': True}}
        )


class AssumeRoleStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        user = iam.User(self, 'myuser')
        role = iam.Role(self, 'MFA_Admin_Role',
                        assumed_by=MFAAccountRootPrincipal(),
                        managed_policies=[iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name('AdministratorAccess')],
                        max_session_duration=core.Duration.hours(8))
        user.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(actions=['sts:AssumeRole'], resources=[role.role_arn]))
```

Note that this doesn't allow for trusting accounts other than the one where the user & role are defined. However, this can be solved easily by passing an account number or instance of `core.Environment` as an argument to the `AssumeRoleStack` initializer. Passing this down to the initializer of `MFAAccountRootPrincipal` you can then manually construct the ARN of the trusted account's root user.

Answer (score 3):

Why invent your own methods when the capability exists in CDK natively?

```
role = iam.Role(
    self,
    "RoleWithCondition",
    description="Role insisting on MFA",
    assumed_by=iam.PrincipalWithConditions(
        principal=iam.AccountPrincipal("123456789012").grant_principal,
        conditions={
            "Bool":  {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": True,
            },
        },
    ).grant_principal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no way to update the existing trust policy. You can possibly raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues).

As a workaround, you can set AccountRootPrincipal as the trusted principal when defining the role, so the user cannot assume it without MFA.

```
iam.Role(
   assumed_by=iam.AccountRootPrincipal()
)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how doing this prevents the user from assuming the role without MFA? From my perspective this seems like an implicit assumption that the root user has MFA set. Coming from a consulting background I can say that this is not always the case (unfortunately).

Comment: As said this is a workaround, which only lets the root user assume this role by default. So "myuser" cannot assume "myrole" without MFA, when you add your PolicyStatement.